# Kill the process using its name inside linux (Python)

Tags: python, linux, unix, process

this works, but it kills every Python process.

```
pkill python
```

However, I cannot do:

```
pkill myscript.py
```

I have also tried *killall*, but with no luck either.
Do I have to user regular expressions?

By the way, I want to do this in a python script with **import os.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you launch the Python subprocess from the same script you are killing it from? If so, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951980/killing-process-in-shell-script) for details.  If not, you can use `pkill`'s -f option to search for the script name in the Python process's argument list, but you still run the risk of killing something you didn't intend to.  See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to have the process write it's `pid` to a file?
In Python you get the pid like this:

```
import os
os.getpid()
```

Killing by name is convenient, but sometimes has undesired consequences as you have seen.

Comment: I think he's trying to kill a specific python script from the (regular) command line, not do something from python

Comment: It applies to both.
I'd like to use the pkill myscript.py ...just to learn how to do it in command line

Comment: @hasen, still it is easier if you have a pid file, `kill 'cat pid'` using backticks instead of `'`

Comment: If he is writing the script, and he chooses a unique name for it, then he can easily guarantee that there will be only one match.

Answer (score 0):

you need to lookup the process id (pid).  You can use the command "ps -A | grep NAME" and then apply "kill -9 PID". These commands can easily be translated to python.

Trying to use a "name" (as in pkill) can yield multiple matches and thus unexpected results (at least in the context set above in the question).

Comment: how's that different from `pkill`?

Comment: You don't NEED to use a pid. You can use whatever means of identifying the process that your process killer allows you to use. All *nix use a pid internally, but sometimes people want to kill all processes matching a pattern, not just a specific pid.

Comment: ... but ultimately you get down to a pid: like I mentioned above, one has more change to kill the unintended process by going through some other means. Been there.

Comment: You may want one of the ps variants that includes the argument data.  E.g. "ps -AFww", "ps -A x", "ps ax", etc.  I always liked "ps aux" or "ps alx".  If you know the parent-pid (PPID) (the spawning process), there's "pstree -p $PPID" or "ps -Fww --ppid 4644".  Awk can easily pull the PID out.  E.g. kill \`ps -Fww | grep foo | awk '{print $2;}'\`  But that is prone to killing the wrong processes by mistake...

Answer (score 0):

`` sudo kill -9 `pgrep python` ``

This command will kill all the running python processes

Comment: This kills all python processes, which is what the OP said they wanted to avoid.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
echo '#!/usr/bin/env python' > myscript
cat myscript.py >>myscript
chmod +x myscript
./myscript
```

Of course you will have to change the code to kill a process named "myscript"
On UNIX systems, an executable file contains a few bytes at the beginning which tell the OS what binary format is being used. If the first two bytes are `#!` then the OS assumes that this is actually a text file which can be executed by another program, and the OS loads the other program and passes to it, the text file.

In this case I probably could have written `#!/usr/bin/python` on the top line, but if your python is in `/usr/local/bin`, then it would not work. Instead, I leverage `env` to get it to search your normal path for python. All UNIX systems have env in /usr/bin. For a bit more info  you can type in `man env`.